# How to freeze nested objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just stumbled upon Object.freeze() function. It seems to be a pretty good feature but how to make whole object (including nested objects) immutable?

For example I can change `innerProp` here:

```
const obj = { prop: { innerProp: 1 } };
obj.prop.innerProp = 5;
console.log(obj.prop.innerProp); // 5
```

Is it possible do freeze nested objects too? (ECMAScript 5/6)

Comment: The only way is to recursively freeze each property too: https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
function deepFreeze (o) {
  Object.freeze(o);
  if (o === undefined) {
    return o;
  }

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function (prop) {
    if (o[prop] !== null
    && (typeof o[prop] === "object" || typeof o[prop] === "function")
    && !Object.isFrozen(o[prop])) {
      deepFreeze(o[prop]);
    }
  });

  return o;
};
```

https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze

It's public domain so you don't have to give credit :D

Comment: `o.hasOwnProperty(prop)` makes no sense

Comment: I mean that this check doesn't make any sense when iterating the own property names of an object.

Comment: It makes as much sense as `if( true && ...` it doesn't hurt anything, but it certainly isn't a useful condition.

Comment: deepFreeze(undefined) fails since getOwnPropertyNames() expect an object

Comment: The deepFreeze fn is bad. Why check if o is undefined after it has been passed to `Object.freeze`? And why not use `o == null` instead of `o === undefined` as then the condition will be `true` for `null` and `undefined`

Comment: 404 on the link: https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze I've seen the project in npm but seems not to be available anymore on Github, MDN provides a similar example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Answer (score 5):

The function can be made much more terse in TS and ES2015.

```
import type { ReadonlyDeep } from 'type-fest';

export function deepFreeze<T>(o: T) {
  Object.values(o).forEach(v => Object.isFrozen(v) || deepFreeze(v));
  return Object.freeze(o) as ReadonlyDeep<T>;
}
```

- Object.isFrozen now returns true for primitive objects.
- Object.values instead of getOwnPropertyNames.

Comment: Fully tested TypeScript implementation: https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/e997cd6ff8d6cf6e51e6bb6146407fc3

Comment: This works for "nice behaved" objects, but (apart from being broken in ES5, where Object.isFrozen(v) throws error if not an object), it blows up if the object has loops

`let o1 = { a: 1 };  let o2 = { b: 2, ox2: o1}; o1.ox1 = o2; `

Comment: ReadOnly is for knowing about compile time, but freeze is about runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = { prop: { innerProp: 1 } };

Object.freeze(obj);
for(let key in obj) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      Object.freeze(obj[key]);
   }
}
obj.prop.innerProp = 5;
console.log(obj); // const obj = { prop: { innerProp: 1 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { readonly } from 'vue/reactive'

let obj = { x: 1 }

obj = readonly(obj)
```

This will create a readonly proxy on the object and changes will have no effect. You can use the reference as a usual object.

You can use only reactive part of the vue 3, it's small import actually, but has lots of useful functionality

Comment: Interesting approach for Vue applications.

Answer (score 0):

One can freeze an object using recursive approach.

```js
const deepFreeze = (param) => {
    Object.keys(param).forEach((val) => {
      if(typeof param[val] === "object"){
        deepFreeze(param[val]);
      }
    });
    return Object.freeze(param);
}

const obj = {
  name: "Vidhi",
  position: "Software Developer",
  travelling: {
    europe:"Rome",
    asia:"Tokyo",
  },
}

deepFreeze(obj);

obj.travelling.asia = "New York";  // cannot assign to read only property "asia" of obj
console.log(obj)
```

One can see in console that object's value has not changed and it will give error if we use **strict mode** in javascript.