# Strategies to avoid unecessary observers in recursive Vue.js components and data

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuejs2

My Vue.js app is currently slow and I have a feeling that there might be too many unnecessary observers.

In my app, I display a tree made of a root node who has children and whose children have children and so on. It looks like this :

```js
{
    label: "root node",
    // ... more props
    children : [
      {
        label:"child A",
        // ... more props
        children:[
           {
             label:"deep child A1"
            //  ... more props
           },
          //  ... more children
        ]
      }, 
      // ... more children
    ]
}
```

There is also a component called "Node" with a prop called "node" where I pass the node as data, each "Node" component has the responsibility of displaying its dynamic props and immediate children and it all starts with the root node.

The problem would be, from my understanding of Vue.js, that the observers are recursive for the children and grand children at each "Node" component, making a lot of redundant observers at depths that dont have an impact to the grand parent nodes.

So my question is, what are the strategies or common patterns to avoid unnecessary observers in case of a recursive data structure like this ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be a problem until you're counting properties in the tens of thousands. You might like to try using `Object.freeze` on the root of your tree to see if it helps performance. While `Object.freeze` is shallow Vue treats it as deep, so no observers should be added. Only objects added to `data` will be augmented with observers, not props. See also https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1988

Comment: I was sure objects passed as props are passed by reference - thus: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/399b53661b167e678e1c740ce788ff6699096734/src/core/observer/index.js#L150

Comment: Thank you. My concern was that because a parent component has all it's descendants data in  it's "data", a change for a deep child would cause the rerender of all it's ancestors. But I have made a test in the "updated" lifecycle hook and I've seen that not all actions in a deep child causes the ancestors to rerender.

Comment: @skirtle, Where did you get the information "While Object.freeze is shallow Vue treats it as deep"? I Think it is true but I did not find any documention mentioned that fact. Many people think it need deep-freeze the whole tree to disable reactivity for nested nodes. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776846/how-to-freeze-nested-objects-in-javascript