# The value of a constant variable inside IIFE is being changed outside of it? How is this possible?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have a constant variable inside an IIFE. This variable is being returned and I don't know why it can be changed.

My code looks like this:

```js
const main = (function(args) {
    "use strict";

    let window = args.window, document = window.document, location = window.location;
    let $ = args.jQuery || null;

    const CONSTANTS = {
        config: {
            appRoot: "http://localhost/development/.../console/",
            apiRoot: "http://localhost/development/.../api/"
        }
     }

    return {
        CONSTANTS
    };
}({ window, jQuery }));

console.log(main.CONSTANTS);
console.log(main.CONSTANTS.config.appRoot = null);  /* returns null */
console.log(main.CONSTANTS);  /* value of appRoot is null now */
```

Now, when I open the console and write `main.CONSTANTS.config.appRoot = null`, it simply returns `null`. I don't want this value to be changed. Am I doing something wrong? Have I missed something too basic?

Also, where is this `main` stored? It is not stored in the window object as `typeof window.main` returns `undefined` & `typeof main` returns `object`.

Comment: Declaring a reference as "const" doesn't make what it refers to immutable.

Comment: A followup question might ask why you need the object to be immutable?  If it's for "security" then you are never going to be satisfied while executing code on the client side.

Comment: Ohh no it's not for security . I am actually using these in some other functions so I don't want these values to be editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```js
const main = (function(args) {
  const CONSTANTS = Object.freeze({
    config: Object.freeze({
      appRoot: "http://localhost/development/.../console/",
      apiRoot: "http://localhost/development/.../api/"
    })
  });

  return Object.freeze({
    CONSTANTS
  });
}());

console.log(main.CONSTANTS);
console.log(main.CONSTANTS.config.appRoot = null);
console.log(main.CONSTANTS.config = null);
console.log(main.CONSTANTS);
```

Comment: Yes, it works for most of my cases, but fails in case of nested objects.

Comment: @Rocker2102 My example has nested objects and it seems to work. Could you be more specific in how to make it not work? (Note: my example uses Object.freeze twice.)

Comment: @Rocker2102 I've edited this to add another Object.freeze in case it was the writable config key that was the issue.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for all your help, but what if I had many more properties in the object. It would lead to many Object.freeze() which I don't think is good?

Comment: @Rocker2102 Perhaps one of the answers on the following post would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776846/how-to-freeze-nested-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Would you mind looking at this: [Example code](https://gist.github.com/Rocker2102/3c6bc68036cb3b0b800d0b6044e14665). Is this ok?

Comment: @Rocker2102 I might not be the person to ask that, and even if I were, I'd probably need to know a fair bit about what you're trying to do and what 'ok' would mean for this code. If you don't think a question about that would fit stackoverflow maybe take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and see if your question would fit that site. Sorry for not being more helpful.