# Typescript Jest Tests seem to be receiving outdated/incorrect source data

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am unsure why there is a discrepency between the recieved function returns by Jest and test data that a script is recieving.

When I run this test:

```
test('inCheck pawn-wrong-direction-black', () => {
  const fen = '6/7/8/9/10/k4K5/10/9/8/7/6 w - 0 1'
  const chess = new HexChess(fen)
  chess.put('g5', { color: WHITE, type: PAWN })
  expect(chess.inCheck()).toEqual(false)
})
```

The test fails as the return value of `chess.inCheck()` is true.

When I run a ts-node script containing:

```
const fen = '6/7/8/9/10/k4K5/10/9/8/7/6 w - 0 1'
const chess = new HexChess(fen)
chess.put('g5', { color: WHITE, type: PAWN })
console.log(chess.inCheck())
```

The printed output is false.

The imports on both files are the same, so I do not see how there could be a difference of result. When debugging the test, it seems that the debugger also sees false *unless* the debugger breakpoint is within the actual test declaration.

It also seems like a test will occasionally change its status from failed to sucess, which confuses me as I am not sure what is changing. It should also be noted that the HexChess class does not depend on any random/third party data and all functions should be 1-1.

I have tried both `npm run test` and the Jest VSCode extension.

jest.config.js

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
```

I am fairly new to both Jest and Typescript, so apologies if I am missing any important information.

Comment: Can we see the `HexChess` impl? Does `HexChess` impl have _any_ async activities ( promise or `async` annotation)? Finally, does `HexChess` reference any variable that is in the module scope? i.e. variables not represented as class fields (vars outside of the class definition).

Comment: The source code is the development branch of https://github.com/owainwilliams1/hexchess.js . Methods are imported into the class for code separation (I realize now that there could be some caching issue). There is no async or promise logic.

Comment: Yep thats it. In node, when you require something, and require it again later you get the same instance. The way you are importing methods like this means your classes don't actually have encapsulated scope. The scope of each method is shared between all instances, which is not desireable.

Comment: Wow. That saves a lot of headache. Thank you very much @adsy

Comment: I should add this way of seperating code is really quite odd, and is causing more noise than help. Having code together doesn't automatically mean "bad" if its truly coupled. If you really want to do it, you need to just add the methods and call the shared function *inside* that and pass the vars to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `HexClass` you are importing methods from some file and assigning them as field vars to the class. Those methods go on to use `this`, but that `this` is actually referencing the function and not the class.

The individual methods now have their own scope, but also that scope will be shared every time you import those files elsewhere as node modules act a little bit like singletons (actually, not strictly speaking, but it works to make sense of this here).

You need to define the methods in the class and not initialise them in field vars from modules. That way they will reference the class scope, and not break class encapsulation.

If you really want to split it up then just do:

example.js

```
const example = (args // pass in scope from class) => ... body

export default example
```

Class

```
import example from './methods/example'

class YourClass {

   example() {
      example(this.stuff) // pass in relevant scope
   }
}
```

In addition, you are setting field vars to constants initialised outside the class scope like `_board` to `EMPTY_BOARD`, probably on the assumption those constants will be copied. However, what actually happens is that all class instances will be referencing and mutating the same `EMPTY_BOARD` "constant". That means each class instance is not encapsulated and there is bleed between them.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogWQAoBUCaB9AQgeQIIBKAIjALwwDeAUDLTAA4BOI9Apo1AJ4BcMA5FFbQ%20VAL4wAhhBihIUKlWAAbKdLgAPCQFt6S1pRq16AVwBGSgJbAYGUyAmMAJrwKtQTgDzRGFsAHMAGhhvXz8APjJ4ZHRsfGIFOlNGVgkAawBJKAAKAEoDOlooAAsLCAA6W3snMqYWdi5IvggQLVZi0JhWJQhWETpRMQVFcGhOzR09SLBWAHd4cd1WXOHIED0ypRA-LNYF9cqHRxyFXe1FsqSUjOzjleb1ze3TidYKu0Pb2VHnxYAmKdm8zOemWXzWr0eOz2rF%20byqRxgAHpETAcEUYGAQABCGAAGS20gARM1Wu1-J1uqxCUA) that demonstrates this issue and a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgWwA5QJ4CEQEMBOATGAXhgAoBKIgPlIG8AoGRmJHEJOHNALhgHIo40XnQC%20MLBBihIUMnTrAANhMkBRAB5ZkiuDHpMkAVwBGigJbAYAfWPZ8PAEpxQ%20ADzQcZsAHMANDA8vb2piRBQMOzxyeSZjHDgsAGsASShyPQYmGCgACzMIADobSIKWNg40Ij4IEAQ4XKD4RQg4YSYRUXkFcGh4TW1dYjA4AHcYDS0kHWjpGp0CxRBvEjh%20qbgi21w8OTpVyfm4hJS03dmQecXl-YHNyLOe2Bv1gCYq4bGJgZmei42rlZrHQvO7bCgAenBMAA4iAQHgAIQwAAyS0kACIBNB0UA) that shows how it can be fixed by ensuring a new object is initialised each time.

Comment: I have just placed all functions back into the main body of the class. Yet the issue still persists, I have run `npx jest --no-cache`, `npx jest --clearCache` and manually deleting jest cache, all to no avail. Updated code in the aformentioned repo.

Comment: Hmm, so you have several variables outside the scope of the class, like MOVES. It looks like these are intended to be constant, so should be ok outside. But you also do not have guarantees they arent mutated. You are careful to clone things, but I think you should try doing a deep object freeze https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776962/1086398 on them to ensure nothing has been missed.

Comment: You could also, if only for the sake of proving if this is the right track, try making them initialised as field vars to rule out bleed in those "constants".

Comment: I can see some other issues here. For example `protected _board: Record<Hexagon, Piece | null> = EMPTY_BOARD`. Every `HexClass` will share boards because of this. You are not making a new copy of EMPTY_BOARD, you are mutating the actual `EMPTY_BOARD` object as it's not copied, it's referenced. Then when you initialise another `HexChess`, they are sharing the same reference, which actually is not constant at all. Wrap these in functions that return the initial state, and then call that as the field initializer. I'm confident this and probably other instances of it as the cause of your issues.

Comment: I forgot to add one confusing thing here if new to TS is `const` var definition does not guarantee that the object cant be mutated as it's not deep in any way. TS const assertions  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions can sometimes help to spot these things. But this one wont be caught because the type on `_board` casts it back.

Comment: Heres a playground to show what i mean https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=61&pln=2&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogWQAoBUCaB9AQgeQIIBKAIjALwwDeAUDLTAA4BOI9Apo1AJ4BcMA5FFbQ+VAL4wAhhBihIUKlWAAbKdLgAPCQFt6S1pRq16AVwBGSgJbAYGUyAmMAJrwKtQTgDzRGFsAHMAGhhvXz8APjJ4ZHRsfGIFOlNGVgkAawBJKAAKAEoDOlooAAsLCAA6W3snMqYWdi5IvggQLVZi0JhWJQhWETpRMQVFcGhOzR09SLBWAHd4cd1WXOHIED0ypRA-LNYF9cqHRxyFXe1FsqSUjOzjleb1ze3TidYKu0Pb2VHnxYAmKdm8zOemWXzWr0eOz2rF+byqRxgAHpETAcEUYGAQABCGAAGS20gARM1Wu1-J1uqxCUA

Comment: And finally a playground of the above issue fixed https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgWwA5QJ4CEQEMBOATGAXhgAoBKIgPlIG8AoGRmJHEJOHNALhgHIo40XnQC+MLBBihIUMnTrAANhMkBRAB5ZkiuDHpMkAVwBGigJbAYAfWPZ8PAEpxQ+ADzQcZsAHMANDA8vb2piRBQMOzxyeSZjHDgsAGsASShyPQYmGCgACzMIADobSIKWNg40Ij4IEAQ4XKD4RQg4YSYRUXkFcGh4TW1dYjA4AHcYDS0kHWjpGp0CxRBvEjh+qbgi21w8OTpVyfm4hJS03dmQecXl-YHNyLOe2Bv1gCYq4bGJgZmei42rlZrHQvO7bCgAenBMAA4iAQHgAIQwAAyS0kACIBNB0UA Hope this helps! Updated answer.